# What are the different endings available in Batman: Arkham Asylum

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

I played through *Batman: Arkham Asylum* a couple times, and remember getting two different endings:

> one where Killer Croc's hand shoots from the surface of Gotham Bay, and the other where its Bane's hand.

**What are the different endings available?  What do or don't do you do to get each ending?  Or are they random?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The endings are completely randomized. You've seen 2 out of the 3 endings. The other hand that you may end up seeing is that of:

> the Scarecrow.

Neither playing the game through on different difficulties nor acquisition of Riddles will affect what ending you receive. And far as players have been able to determine, it's either completely random, or it's based on variables obfuscated enough that the playerbase can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

They are 3 different endings and they are random. So nothing to do... it just happens in a random way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's random. It depends on which of the three you died to the most.